# Переход на следующую страницу при "доскролле" до низа страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доскроллив до конца страницы должен произойти переход на следующую страницу с задержкой. [Сайт пример](https://kraynev.ru/) , но тут все на ангуляре и не понятно.

Делаю так, при "доскролле" начинает срабатывать (если срабатывает) `setTimeout` и переход, если в это время начать скроллить вверх, переход должен отменяться:

```js
var scrollY =  $(window).scrollTop(),
  currentOffset = scrollY + window.innerHeight,
  element = $('footer'),
  bg = $('.next-route__overlay'),
  offset = element.offset().top,
  adress = $('.route-link').data('link'),
  timeout,
  show = false;

  console.log(offset + ' ' + currentOffset);

$(window).scroll(function(){

  if(offset <= $(window).scrollTop()+window.innerHeight){  
    show = true;    
    bg.show();
    timeout = setTimeout(window.location.replace(adress), 5500);      
  }else {
    show = false;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }

});
```

```css
main {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.next-route__overlay {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 4rem;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .5;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer>
  <div class="route-link" data-link="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">
    <div class="next-route__btn">
      <!-- <img src="images/ring-alt.gif" class="ico" alt=""> -->
      <span>Услуги</span>
    </div>

    <div class="next-route__overlay"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**Вопрос:** как можно осуществить автоматический переход на следующую страницу "доскроллив" до конца страницы средствами jquery (js), но при обратном сролле переход должен отменяться?

Comment: может запоминать что вернул `setTimeout` и в `else` блоке вызывать [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в вашем коде две проблемы.

1. в качестве аргумента `setTimeout` вы пишите выражение, в данном случае оно вычисляется сразу, т.к. это не ссылка на функцию, а ее вызов. Вам следует использовать функцию, внутри которой уже будет заменен `location`
2. Событие скролла вызывается постоянно, в итоге вы несколько раз подряд взываете `setTimeout` каждый раз генерируется новый хэндл. Когда же вы начинаете крутить вверх, то очищаете только последний сгенерированный таймаут, а предыдущие созданные остаются и срабатывают. Поэтому назначать новый `setTimeout` нужно  только в том случае, если он еще не вызыван.

```js
var scrollY =  $(window).scrollTop(),
  currentOffset = scrollY + window.innerHeight,
  element = $('footer'),
  bg = $('.next-route__overlay'),
  offset = element.offset().top,
  adress = $('.route-link').data('link'),
  timeout = null,
  show = false;

  console.log(offset + ' ' + currentOffset);

$(window).scroll(function(){

  if(offset <= $(window).scrollTop()+window.innerHeight){  
    show = true;    
    bg.show();
    if(!timeout){
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                      window.location.replace(adress); 
                   }, 5500);    
    }
  }
  else {
    show = false;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  }

});
```

```css
main {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.next-route__overlay {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 4rem;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .5;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer>
  <div class="route-link" data-link="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">
    <div class="next-route__btn">
      <!-- <img src="images/ring-alt.gif" class="ico" alt=""> -->
      <span>Услуги</span>
    </div>

    <div class="next-route__overlay"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: @HamSter пофиксил, `timeout = null`после `clearTimeout`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!